# Django throwing UNIQUE Constraint failed even after adding unique = False

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am developing a custom usermodel for my application in django, by using AbstractUser.
But I am getting a UNIQUE constraint failed error while using `add user +` from django admin.
I have also tried to add `unique = False` in the EmailField

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    rollno = models.CharField(null=True,unique=True,max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True,null=True,unique=False)
```

Error :

```
....
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: Accounts_user.email
[28/Jun/2022 05:54:58] "POST /admin/Accounts/user/add/ HTTP/1.1" 500 233697
```

The add form does not have a email field, submits a blank email.

(PS : I can add user by signup form of my application, `change user` of django admin is also working.)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the above code, there should not be any problem with migrations. i think your old migrations are creating problem here. check your old migrations and delete them.

Comment: HI @I'mSRJ , Thank you ! I was so silly I just forgot to apply the migrations :}